# Replace objects in queryset in view before sending to template?

Tags: python, django

How to replace objects in queryset in view before sending to template in django?

models

```
class Level(models.Model):
    [...]
    previous_level = ForeignKey('Level', blank=True, null=True)

class CompletedLevel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('Auth.user')
    level = models.ForeignKey('Level')
    result = models.IntegerField()
```

views:

```
levels = Level.objects.filter(previous_level=None)
for i,level in enumerate(modules):
    try:
        #if level is completed with result > 80 then replace this level with next level
        if CompletedLevel.objects.get(result__gt=80):
            modules[i] = Module.objects.get(previous_level=level)
    except:
        pass
```

getting error:

```
'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: i got modules (list of objects) from database and i want to replace some objects with another (if object passing if statement -> replace)

Comment: you can use filter, and then append. I would not recommend you doing it this way (I guess you cant do it i mean)

Comment: @karthikr question edited to show you what exactly im doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post how the module gets used in template? As recommended by karthikr, you should filter the queryset instead of modifying its inner state, because a `QuerySet` instance represents a collection of objects from DB with their contents as the snapshot at the time point of the evaluation of the queryset (If you *really* need to modify it, check `modules._result_cache` after the queryset has been evaulated...).

If the queryset is iterated in template, you could write a generator like:

```
def modified_module():
   for i, module in enumerate(modules):
      if [...] :
          try:
              yield Module.objects.get( [...] )
          except:
              yield module
      else:
          yield module
 # and iterate on modified_module() in template
```

Or you could cope w/ a copied version:

```
modules = list(modules)
# do modifications
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for response, question edited to show you what exactly im doing. What do you suggest to do?